# Hierarchical Dependecy Injection in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have a root component which is AppComponent , I have injected a service in root component (ProductService) which I am trying to resolve in one of the child component(ProductList) . I am getting a error in

> No provider for ProductService! (ProductListComponent -> ProductService)

Here is the code for Root component and Child component

```js
import {
  Component
}
from 'angular2/core'
import {
  ProductListComponent
}
from './products/product-list.component'
import {
  ProductService
}
from './products/product.service'

/**
 * AppComponent
 */

@
Component({
  selector: 'pm-app',
  template: `
     <div>
       <h1>{{PageTitle}}</h1>
      <pm-products></pm-products>
     </div>
    `,
  providers: [ProductService],
  directives: [ProductListComponent]

})
export class AppComponent {
  PageTitle: string = "Acme Product Management";
}
```

ProductListComponent

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: 'app/products/product-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/Products/products-list.component.css'],
    pipes: [ProductFilterPipe],
    directives: [StarComponent]
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
    PageTitle: string = "Product List";
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imagemargin: number = 2;
    showImage: boolean = false;
    filterBy: string;
    products: IProduct[];
    
    constructor(public _productService:ProductService){
        
    }
  }
```

My understanding on angular 2 DI is, If the service is injected in root that it get injected to it's child component . Do I have to do anything extra?

Comment: IMHO all looks fine. Can you try `new ProductService()` in the constructor of `ProductListComponent` instead of injecting it? Just to check if this results in a more useful error message.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I tried it and I am able to use it. Also I have added the Provider parameter to the Product list component and even that is working fine. Only the Root component to child is having a problem.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "added the Provider parameter to the Product list".

Comment: If I add the Provider parameter then I am use the product list component .       I mean when i provide code like  @component({provider:[ProductService]}); in Produclist component , it is able to resolve.  I was expecting the angular DI will inject the providers of rootcomponent into it's child

Comment: That's right. No idea why it doesn't work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You do have `import { ProductService } from './products/product.service'` in your `ProductListComponent`, right?